# How to rename columns in ComplexHeatmaps

Tags: heatmap, complexheatmap

I need to rename the name of the columns for example: cmc_20_3 to f/d_3 and so on, is it possible to do this?

```
h1 <- Heatmap(mat.scaled, cluster_rows = F,  column_labels = colnames(mat.scaled), name="Z-score", cluster_columns = T, col=col_zscore,  show_row_names=F)here[![enter image description here][1]][1]enter code here
```

[image]